# Generated Texture coordinate per mesh island

Tags: scripting

I wonder how is possible to get Generated texture coordinates (from the "Texture Coordinate" node) but **per each mesh island**, so that for each mesh island I have got coordinates started from 0 (**as if they are all separate objects**). I suppose that by having Random Per Island value (from "Geometry node") is possible to do it most likely only by scripting.
Any advice, currently can't find a solution.
[image]

So let consider the following example, suppose we have an object which actually incorporates 3 cubic meshes (top instance), and the example below is three separate objects each of them has only one cubic mesh. You can observe how, in the top example, the Generated texture coordinate is stretched along with all cubic meshes. So my purpose is to get Generated coordinate for an object with multiple mesh islands (top example) but as if each mesh island is a separate object (bottom example).
[image]
I can suppose that since Random per island gives us a sort of id for each mesh island utilizing it we somehow can remap Generated coordinates for the islands

Comment: Removing my answer, so the question will get more attention. I agree with @Secrop, using UV map is a good workaround here, but of course it is not the answer for the question.

Comment: UV is merely a solution if there are few meshes, isn't my case

Comment: With a bit of python, UV would still be the better choice. For GenCoords you really need to split all islands into their own objects (which you can leave linked together)... Even if you'd change Blender source code to allow GenCoors for islands, that alone would break in other softwares.

Comment: @Secrop Since Random per island gives us a sort of id for each mesh island utilizing it we somehow can remap Generated coordinates for the islands - my thoughts

Comment: @VitaliiSadovshikov Then python is your best friend.. Do you want to scale each island to fill the whole UV space each and keep U/V ratios, or a full rescale of the island's bounding rect to the UV space?

Comment: @Secrop Sorry for the delay I was away. So I have elaborated my question a little bit can you take a glance again

Comment: If all your instances are just squared planes (like you now have in your question), all you need to do is just reset the UV map (in edit mode > U > reset).

Comment: @Secrop Nope, It's just a simple example, I am dealing with 3D objects

Answer (score 2):

As pointed in the comments, the solution would be to use Python, find the Min() and Max() values for all Coordinates in each Island, and then apply `Coordfinal= (coord - min)/(max - min)` to those vertices.

Since the default vertex structure doesn't have room for these values, your best option is to store them into Vertex_Layer_Floats, and use the AttributeNode to access them in the NodeEditor.

Here's a small script that does that:

```
import bmesh, bpy, numpy
from collections import defaultdict


class GenIslands:
    def __init__(self):
        self.obj = bpy.context.object.data
        self.bm = bmesh.new()
        self.bm.from_mesh(self.obj)
        self.uvlayer = self.bm.loops.layers.uv.active
        self.face_to_verts = defaultdict(set)
        self.vert_to_faces = defaultdict(set)
        for face in self.bm.faces:
            for loop in face.loops:
                self.face_to_verts[face.index].add(loop.vert.index)
                self.vert_to_faces[loop.vert.index].add(face.index)
    
        
    def addToIsland(self, face_id):
        if face_id in self.faces_left:
            self.current_island.add(face_id)
            self.faces_left.remove(face_id)
            verts = self.face_to_verts[face_id]
            for vert in verts:
                connected_faces = self.vert_to_faces[vert]
                if connected_faces:
                    for face in connected_faces:
                        self.addToIsland(face)
        
    
    def getIslands(self):
        self.islands = []
        self.faces_left = set(self.face_to_verts.keys())
        while len(self.faces_left) > 0:
            face_id = list(self.faces_left)[0]
            self.current_island = set()
            self.addToIsland(face_id)
            self.islands.append(self.current_island)
           
        return self.islands
    
    def addLayers(self):
        if "islandX" in self.obj.vertex_layers_float:
            self.fx = self.obj.vertex_layers_float["islandX"]
            self.fy = self.obj.vertex_layers_float["islandY"]
            self.fz = self.obj.vertex_layers_float["islandZ"]
        else:
            self.fx = self.obj.vertex_layers_float.new(name = "islandX")
            self.fy = self.obj.vertex_layers_float.new(name = "islandY")
            self.fz = self.obj.vertex_layers_float.new(name = "islandZ")
        
    def generateCoordinates(self):
        self.addLayers()
        islands = self.getIslands()
        cnt = len(self.obj.vertices)
        coords = numpy.zeros((cnt * 3))
        self.obj.vertices.foreach_get("co", coords)
        coords.shape = (cnt, 3)
        for island in islands:
            verts = list(set(v for p in [poly for poly in self.obj.polygons if poly.index in island] for v in p.vertices))
            CO = coords[verts]
            cmin = CO.min(axis=0)
            cmax = CO.max(axis=0)
            generated = (CO - cmin) / (cmax - cmin)
            coords[verts] = generated
        self.fx.data.foreach_set("value", coords[:,0].flatten())
        self.fy.data.foreach_set("value", coords[:,1].flatten())
        self.fz.data.foreach_set("value", coords[:,2].flatten())
            
tool = GenIslands()
tool.generateCoordinates()
```

(some of this code isn't mine, but I don't recall where I got it)

In the Node Editor, you just need to add three AttributeNodes, pointing to "islandX", "islandY" and "islandZ", join the 'Facs' with a CombineXYZ and use the output vector as your new Generated Coordinates.